# Change border Primefaces 5.1 specific column

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable, border

i can change `border-right-width` of all my datatable.

```
.ui-datatable tbody td {
    border-right-width:3px;
}
```

*But how can i change border of a specific column?*

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
<p:column headerText="2" styleClass="column2">
    ...
</p:column>
```

and

```
<style>
    .ui-datatable tbody td.column2{
        border-right-width:5px;
        border-left-width:5px;
    }
    .ui-datatable thead th.column2{
        border-right-width:5px;
        border-left-width:5px;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: not work =/ 
is it not working because i have a columngroup too?

Comment: WORK!! i just did a "clear cache" in my chrome and it works now.